# Identify whether the text in the shortest 'Text' field is contained within all other 'Text' fields in other rows for the same 'ID'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I something like the following dataset:

```
ID   Text
1    The
1    The Quick
1    The Quick Brown
2    Fox
2    Fox
3    Jumps
3    Over The
3    Over The L
3    Over The Lazy
```

I need to have code which tells me whether the text in the shortest 'Text' field is contained within all other fields for the same 'ID'.

The output should look like this:

```
ID   Text              Result
1    The               Yes
1    The Quick         Yes
1    The Quick Brown   Yes
2    Fox               Yes
2    Fox               Yes
3    Jumps             No
3    Over The          No
3    Over The L        No
3    Over The Lazy     No
```

In reality some of the text fields are very long and this will be accross thousands of rows worth of data.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `The Quick` isn't the shortest so why have it `Yes`? Same For `The Quick Brown`

Comment: What are you going to do when you have a tie for the shortest (like ID 2) but the two values are not the same?

Comment: Ideally the result would show 'No' in that case also. It wouldn't really matter which one was picked in that case as long as they do not contain each other.

Comment: @lad2025 I need all fields in the ID to show all 'Yes' or all 'No'. Because The Quick contains The it was 'Yes'

Comment: `Over The` contains `Over` so why answer is No?

Comment: @lad2025 I have made an edit as not both tables were consistent. The reason is because Jumps is the shortest and is not contained by any of the others in ID3

Comment: I hope you don't expect this to be fast because you are going to have to evaluate every single row in the table which is not going to scale well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with shortestPerID as (
    select A.ID as ID, A.Text as Text from
        (select ID, Text, MAX(Len(Text)) as Length from TABLE_NAME group by ID, Text) as A
    right join
        (select ID, min(len(Text)) as Length from TABLE_NAME group by ID) as B
    on (A.ID = B.ID and A.Length = B.Length)
)    

select A.ID, A.Text, 
       case when B.Text is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as Result
from TABLE_NAME as A left join shortestPerID as B
ON (A.ID = B.ID and charindex(B.Text, A.Text) > 0)
```

First, `CTE` is to use table with shortest texts per ID. Then simple join does the trick :)

Try this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc4ba/13).

This is the result, it's different: for ID=3 and Text='Jumps' it says yes, because 'Jumps' is contained in itself :)

```
ID   Text              Result
1    The               Yes
1    The Quick         Yes
1    The Quick Brown   Yes
2    Fox               Yes
2    Fox               Yes
3    Jumps             Yes
3    Over The          No
3    Over The L        No
3    Over The Lazy     No
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by @JohnRC to get `'No'` for the shortest `Text`, you can use other `JOIN` condition in `select` statement:

```
on (A.ID = B.ID and A.Length = B.Length and B.Text <> A.Text)
```

Comment: If you don't want the case of the shortest text being tested against itself, you could add `.and B.Text <> A.Text ` in the final ON .. clause. Then ID=3 Text='Jumps' would show 'No'.

Comment: But then it would differ on ID=1 and Text='Yes' :) and ID=2 and Text='Fox', so I will stick to my solution :) But thank you for advice.

Comment: Oh yes, then in the CTE you could add a `COUNT(ID)` to the `SELECT ... GROUP BY ...` and test for count <> 1 in the final part instead..

Comment: Thank you for this. And also for using SQL fiddle. Very useful indeed!

Comment: @JohnRC could you please write out the code with the edits you suggest for me? I cannot seem to get them working but I would like to have the shortest text also show no if the others do. Thanks

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I get " Invalid column name 'Text' " error.

Comment: I have posted a suggested solution below using temporary tables instead.

Answer (score 3):

Ok here we go.
First, you identify the length of each value and identify what that value is for each ID that has the shortest length (OR simply identify it with a qualify statement).

```
select ID, text as shortest_text, length(text) as txt_length from table
qualify row_number() over(partition by ID order by txT_length)=1

OR

select ID, text as shortest_text 
from table z
inner join (
select ID, max(txt_length) as max_length from (
select ID, text, length(text) as txt_length from table ) x)y
on z.Id=y.ID and length(z.text)=y.txt_length
```

Then you will have to basically join this to the original table and see if that value is contained in the different rows, per ID.

```
select ID, text, shortest_text, case when text like '%'+shortest_text+'%' then 1 else 0 end as contains_shortest_text
from table a
left join ([previous query, if you use Teradata I recommend the first option]) b
on a.ID=b.ID
```

And lastly, you will identify if ALL the rows for each ID contain that value or not.

```
select ID, text, min(contains_shortest_text) over(partition by ID) as all_contain_shortest_text
from ([previous query]) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion, using temporary tables (SQL Server 2014):

```
        -- Get the minimum text length and number of entries per ID 
        SELECT ID
            , Min(LEN(text)) MINTL
            , Count(ID) IDCount 
            INTO #MINTL 
            FROM TABLE_NAME 
            GROUP BY ID;

        -- Get all the minimum text(s) and entry count per ID
        SELECT DISTINCT X.* 
            INTO #MINTEXT 
            FROM (
                SELECT A.ID, A.text MinText, B.IDCount 
                    FROM TABLE_NAME A
                    JOIN #MINTL B
                        ON A.ID = B.ID AND LEN(A.Text) = B.MinTL 
                ) X;

        -- Count the matches for each minimum text per ID
        SELECT A.ID
             , A.MinTEXT
             , A.IDCount
             , COUNT(B.ID) MatchCount
            INTO #MATCHES
            FROM #MINTEXT A
                JOIN TABLE_NAME B
                    ON A.ID = B.ID 
                    AND charindex(A.MinText, B.Text) > 0  
            GROUP BY A.ID
                   , A.MinText
                   , A.IDCount;

        -- Produce the result, only say Yes if the number of matches = the entry count
        SELECT A.ID
             , A.Text
             , CASE 
                   WHEN B.IDCOUNT > B.MatchCount THEN 'No' 
                   ELSE 'Yes' END Result
            FROM TABLE_NAME A
            JOIN #MATCHES B 
                ON A.ID = B.ID
            ORDER BY A.ID, A.Text;

        DROP TABLE #MINTL;
        DROP TABLE #MINTEXT;
        DROP TABLE #MATCHES;
```

generating this result with the same input as in the question

```
ID          Text                                               Result
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ------
1           The                                                Yes
1           The Quick                                          Yes
1           The Quick Brown                                    Yes
2           Fox                                                Yes
2           Fox                                                Yes
3           Jumps                                              No
3           Over The                                           No
3           Over The L                                         No
3           Over The Lazy                                      No
```